# How to set background image for Edit (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, background, editbox

how can i have a image for Editbox background ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is very possible, indeed. In your form, define

```
private
  { Private declarations }
  FBitmap: TBitmap;
  FBrush: HBRUSH;
protected
  procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
```

and do

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  FBitmap.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Pictures\AS20Utv.bmp');
  FBrush := 0;
  FBrush := CreatePatternBrush(FBitmap.Handle);
end;
```

and

```
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_CTLCOLOREDIT, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
      if (Message.LParam = Edit1.Handle) and (FBrush <> 0) then
      begin
        SetBkMode(Message.WParam, TRANSPARENT);
        Message.Result := FBrush;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Of course you can wrap this into a component of your own, say `TEditEx`. If I get time over, I might do this. (And, notice that there is no need to buy an expensive (and maybe not that high-quality) component pack from a third-party company.)

[image: Custom edit background]

Comment: Why WM_CTLCOLOREDIT?  It won't get called when the control is disabled.  Why not WM_ERASEBACKGROUND and WM_PRINTCLIENT?

Comment: +1 because someone have down voted for a working code ! it works

Comment: To be clear WM_CTLCOLOREDIT is sent when the control is Enabled, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC when it is disabled.  Probably wise to grey scale (or similar) your background for the latter to make it clear that the control will not accept input.  I see that Andreas has now edited the code to handle WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC as well as WM_CTLCOLOREDIT.